# How to get the PHP var after Jquery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use `$.ajax` to send some data to testajax.php`enter code here` where data are processing. Result of this proces is link. How to get access to this? I think about sessions or cookies. Set in session `$test`  and get access in another files.

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'testajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:  console.log('success');
      data: { json : jsonObj }

    });
```

In testajax.php I have someting like this

```
echo "PDF: <a href=images/test.pdf>$dir.pdf</a>";
$test = "PDF: <a href=images/test.pdf>$dir.pdf</a>";
```

How to get the `$test` or output the `echo` after call `$.ajax`

Comment: you want to display the link which is created in testajax.php?

Comment: yes this I  my intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use success' function to get request from PHP.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'testajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: { json : jsonObj }
      success:  function(data) {
         var request = data;
         console.log(data);
         $('#link_container').html(data);
      }
});
```

Your console now holds `PDF: <a href=images/test.pdf>($dir content).pdf</a>`.
Also the variable `request` holds the same result that you can use anywhere in the script.
Result is appended to `#link_container`.

Comment: No. It can receive output of 'testajax.php' (which is text/html) since `dataType` option is set to 'json'.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You have to set `dataType` option to `'html'` or `'text'`

Comment: Or set header in PHP side to `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: No. Setting header is not enough to make it work. 'testajax.php' should return valid `JSON` as well

Comment: I have to change  `console.log(data);` to `console.log(response);` and It's working thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `success()` method for display the result.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'testajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:  function (data){ // <= define handler for manupulate the response
         $('#result').html(data);
       }
      data: { json : jsonObj }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code It may help you.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'testajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { json : jsonObj },
 onSuccess: successFunc,
  onFailure:  failureFunc

    });

function successFunc(response){

    alert(response);
}

function failureFunc(response){

     alert("Call is failed" );
    alert(response);
}
```

Comment: what you get in alert. @konadrian